# edit_tag_form_fields is depricated but tag_edit_form_fields doesn't work

Tags: custom-field, tags

I need to create, retrieve, update and display a custom field in Wordpress tags. 
This code works for displaying the custom field, but its deprecated.

```
function tag_edit_form_fields ( $term ) {

?>
    <tr class="form-field">
        <th scope="row"><label for="term-colorpicker">Custom Field: </label></th>
        <td>
            <input type="custom_field" name="_custom_field" value=" <?php echo $custom_value; ?>" id="term-custom_term" />
            <p class="description">This is a custom field.</p>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <?php
 }
add_action('edit_tag_form_fields','tag_edit_form_fields');
```

Using the **new** function `{$taxonomy}_edit_form_fields` as `tag_edit_form_fields` doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While adding the tags to this stack exchange question, I added `tags` and the hint showed up as `post_tag`.

[image]

So, I tried

```
add_action('post_tag_edit_form_fields','tag_edit_form_fields');
```

and it works!